# Jackson: Adjust ObjectMapper to ignore specific attributes from a class

Tags: java, json, junit, jackson, resteasy

I'm writing tests for RESTful services in a legacy application using Resteasy Client and Embedded Jaxrs Server. I'm facing problems with Serialization/Deserialization using Jackson with a peculiar Entity, which I'm not supposed to do any changes. This Entity has:

- A public "getter" that only performs logic (no equivalent field) and should be serializable, but not deserializable;
- A private field used for certain controls and persistence, but without public getter/setter, shouldn't be Serialized/Deserialized;

While in the application our Front-end never sends those attributes back (so they're never deserialized), in my unit tests they are failing due to "org.codehaus.jackson.map.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field". If both properties above have their public getters/setters the test won't fail, but then again I'm not supposed to do changes to the code and those methods would break the architeture of those classes.

I've tweaked my Object Mapper but no configuration was able to deal with this scenario. Either one or another ends up being not found. Is there a way to turn of serialization in those cases by adjusting only my Object Mapper to ignore those properties? Or is it mandatory to have the code altered somehow?

Thanks!

(Small sample)

```
// Entity
public class Entidade {
    private int numero;
    private String dado;
    private boolean naoUsado = false;

    public Entidade() { /**/ }

    public Entidade(int numero, String dado) {
        this.numero = numero;
        this.dado = dado;
    }

    public int getNumero() {
        return numero;
    }

    public void setNumero(int numero) {
        this.numero = numero;
    }

    public String getDado() {
        return dado;
    }

    public void setDado(String dado) {
        this.dado = dado;
    }

    public String getTeste() {
        return "Regra de negócio de leitura";
    }
}

// Embedded Server Helper
public class ServidorEmbarcadoRestEasy {

    private static final int POOL_SIZE = 9999;
    private static final int PORTA = 5555;
    private static final String HOST = "localhost";

    private TJWSEmbeddedJaxrsServer servidor;
    private ResteasyClient resteasyClient;

    private ServidorEmbarcadoRestEasy(Object webservice, Class<?>... providers) {
        this.servidor = new TJWSEmbeddedJaxrsServer();
        this.resteasyClient = new ResteasyClientBuilder().
                connectionPoolSize(POOL_SIZE).
                connectionCheckoutTimeout(100, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS).
                build();

        servidor.setPort(PORTA);
        servidor.setBindAddress(HOST);        
        servidor.getDeployment().getResources().add(webservice);
        servidor.setSecurityDomain(null);
        servidor.start();

        ResteasyProviderFactory factory = servidor.getDeployment().getDispatcher().getProviderFactory();

        for (Class<?> c : providers) {
            factory.registerProvider(c);
        }
    }

    public static ServidorEmbarcadoRestEasy iniciar(Object webservice, Class<?>... providers) {
        ServidorEmbarcadoRestEasy servidorEmbarcado = new ServidorEmbarcadoRestEasy(webservice, providers);
        return servidorEmbarcado;
    }

    public void fechar() {
        servidor.stop();
    }

    private String getUrlCompleta(String uri) {
        final String base = "http://%s:%s/%s";
        return String.format(base, HOST, PORTA, uri);
    }

    private Builder request(String uri, List<String> queryParams) {
        String urlCompleta = getUrlCompleta(uri);
        ResteasyWebTarget target = resteasyClient.target(urlCompleta);

        for (String s : queryParams) {
            String[] chaveValor = s.split("=");
            String chave = chaveValor[0];           
            String valor = chaveValor[1];
            target = target.queryParam(chave, valor);
        }

        return target.request();
    }

    private Builder request(String uri) {
        if (uri.contains("?")) {
            String[] urlFracionada = uri.split("\\?");          
            String baseUri = urlFracionada[0];
            String paramString = urlFracionada[1];
            String[] paramArray = paramString.split("&");
            List<String> parametros = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(paramArray));

            if (!parametros.isEmpty()) {
                return request(baseUri, parametros);
            }
        }

        String urlCompleta = getUrlCompleta(uri);
        return resteasyClient.target(urlCompleta).request();
    }

    public Response get(String url) {
        return request(url).buildGet().invoke();
    }

    public Response delete(String url) {
        return request(url).buildDelete().invoke();
    }

    public Response put(String url, Object payload) {
        return request(url).buildPut(Entity.json(payload)).invoke();
    }

    public Response post(String url, Object payload) {
        return request(url).buildPost(Entity.json(payload)).invoke();
    }

}

// Jackson Provider
public class JacksonTestsProvider extends JacksonJsonProvider {
    public static ObjectMapper getMapper() {
        return new ObjectMapper()       
                .configure(DeserializationConfig.Feature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void writeTo(Object arg0, Class<?> arg1, Type arg2, Annotation[] arg3, MediaType arg4,
            MultivaluedMap<String, Object> arg5, OutputStream arg6) throws IOException {
        super.setMapper(getMapper());
        super.writeTo(arg0, arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4, arg5, arg6);
    }

    @Override
    public Object readFrom(Class<Object> type, Type genericType, Annotation[] annotations, MediaType mediaType,
            MultivaluedMap<String, String> httpHeaders, InputStream entityStream) throws IOException {
        super.setMapper(getMapper());
        return super.readFrom(type, genericType, annotations, mediaType, httpHeaders, entityStream);
    }
}

// Unit Tests
public class ServidorEmbarcadoRestEasyTest {

    @Path("meuservico")
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public static class ServicoTeste {
        private Map<Integer, Entidade> entidades = new HashMap<>();

        public ServicoTeste() {
            for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
                entidades.put(i, new Entidade(i, "Teste " + i));
            }           
        }

        @GET
        @Path("minha-entidade")
        public Response getEntidade() {
            return Response.ok(new Entidade(9999, "Nova entidade")).build();
        }

        @GET
        @Path("minha-entidade/{id}")
        public Response getEntidade(@PathParam("id") Integer id) {
            Entidade retorno = entidades.get(id);

            if (retorno == null) {
                return Response.status(Status.BAD_REQUEST).build();
            } else {
                return Response.ok(retorno).build();
            }
        }
    }

    private static ServidorEmbarcadoRestEasy servidor;
    private static ServicoTeste servico;

    @BeforeClass
    public static void setUpBeforeClass() throws Exception {
        servico = new ServicoTeste();
        servidor = ServidorEmbarcadoRestEasy.iniciar(servico, 
                JacksonTestsProvider.class);
    }

    @AfterClass
    public static void tearDownAfterClass() throws Exception {
        servidor.fechar();
    }

    @Test
    public void deveFazerGetComSucesso() {
        Response response = servidor.get("meuservico/minha-entidade");
        assertEquals(Status.OK.getStatusCode(), response.getStatus());

        Entidade entidade = response.readEntity(Entidade.class);
        assertEquals(9999, entidade.getNumero());
        assertEquals("Nova entidade", entidade.getDado());

        response = servidor.get("meuservico/minha-entidade/98");
        assertEquals(Status.OK.getStatusCode(), response.getStatus());

        entidade = response.readEntity(Entidade.class);
        assertEquals(98, entidade.getNumero());
        assertEquals("Teste 98", entidade.getDado());
    }

}
```

Comment: have you tried to declare your private field `naoUsado` `transient` ?

Comment: @MedhiRedjem this attribute is calculated, persisted and used for internal controls. It can't be set to Transient. :-(